# Click e Toggle com jquery, delay de 1 click

Tags: javascript, jquery

tô com um pequeno probleminha que não sei como resolver, tenho uma div, que ao clicar nela ele adiciona algo com load(), e fica alternando esse evento com o toggle(), para adicionar e retirar também, só que quando eu dou o primeiro click ele não exibe de imediato, somente quando eu clico uma segunda vez, aí ele passa a executar normalmente o evento click, segue o código:

```
$('.more .ico').click(function(){
    $('.more .toggle').toggle( 50, function(){
        $(this).load("frames/menu-drop.php");
    });
});
<div class="more">
    <div class="ico"></div>
    <div class="toggle"></div>
</div>
```

Quando clicar no ico, era pra aplicar o load() na .toggle

Eu entendo o porque de ocorrer isso, mas não sei uma forma de solucionar, e caso alguém sugira usar o on('click') já tentei também.

Comment: Como está o HTML? Talvez o problema esteja na estrutura.

Comment: Já tentou com .trigger('click', function(){});

Comment: coloca um exemplo deste comportamento no jsfiddler ou codepen

Comment: Vou tentar agora o trigger

Comment: Com o trigger ele não está funcionando... Não executa a ação e no console não aparece nenhum erro

Comment: Colocarei o exemplo no codepen

Comment: Só que ao invés do load(), terei de usar para ocultar o mostrar com o css, mas é a mesma coisa, dá o mesmo acontecimento, pois não estou tendo esse problema só com ele, mas sim quando uso o on('click') junto com o toggle e até entendo, só não sei como resolver

Comment: Bom coloquei lá, só que funciona normalmente, coloquei exatamente como se encontra no meu, mas lá funciona normalmente, mas o meu não

Comment: Acredito que o problema esteja no fato de ser o load().

Answer (score 0):

O problema que o toggle está "escondendo" sua **div** no primeiro click porque ele está visível. Usar **toggle** pode causar um estado indesejado. Tente usar o **show()** ou **fadeIn()** no lugar de **toggle**. Não faz sentido chamar o load quando você está escondendo a **div**. Para iniciar a **div** escondida defina o **visible: hidden** no atributo da classe css **.toggle** ou direto no atributo **style**

Comment: Cara o toggle eu usei para poder ficar alternando o efeito, quando clicar carrega o$(this).load("frames/menu-drop.php"); dentro da div toggle. e ao clicar novamente ele esconde. mas com o Show, dá certo para mostrar.